quantum circuit for 0-1 matrix
Given a $0-1$ $2^n*2^n$ matrix, each row has only one 1
each column has only one 1.
Such an unitary matrix can be described by an invertible function $f(x) : [1,2^n]\rightarrow [1,2^n]$, Given such a matrix or such a function.
Is there a common way to construct a quantum circuit to implement such an unitary matrix?

What you are looking for is how to create permutation matrices. This and this post could be helpful.

Also this post is relevant regarding the complexity.

Even though the posts above are related to this question, I still believe no one has provided a satisfactory answer. Here @Callum mentions a procedure given in Nielsen & Chuang, but that is a lot more general than just for permutations, and it's hard to distill it to this specific case (also inefficient). An example using pyket is also provided, but the inner workings of the "ToffoliBox" are not explained. Just mentioning this in case someone with the answer sees the comments and thinks it's not worth replying.

I agree with @diemilio. Would be nice to have a better explanation of the complexity in particular. I don't have an explanation I'm satisifed with myself yet.

It would certainly depend on how the permutation was given… for example as a cycle decomposition versus a square matrix as the OP suggests..
